# Delete space in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I have a problem setting the property of `footmisc` library to set footnotes to bottom.

I already did the following code, but footnotes downs a bit not completely as I want.

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

**Without `[bottom]` property**

[image]

**With `[bottom]` property**

[image]

This is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,
bottom=2.54cm,
left=2.54cm,
right=2.54cm,
headheight=17pt, 
includehead,includefoot,
heightrounded,
]{geometry} % 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\fancypagestyle{myportland}{
    \fancyhead{}% clear all header 
    \fancyfoot{}% clear all footer
    \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields  
    \fancyhead[L,C,R]{}
    \fancyfoot[L,C,R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Página \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \newgeometry{
        top=2.54cm,
        bottom=2.54cm,
        left=2.54cm,
        right=2.54cm,
        headheight=17pt, % as per the warning by fancyhdr
        includehead,includefoot,
        heightrounded % to avoid spurious underfull messages
    }
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myportland}
Something.\footnote{Here is a footnote.} Something else.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi risus lacus, suscipit vehicula ullamcorper a, tempus consectetur.}

\end{document}
```

With an **output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The desired output is achieved by setting the `\footskip` value. The `footskip` reduces all the available white spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,
bottom=2.54cm,
left=2.54cm,
right=2.54cm,
headheight=17pt,
includehead,includefoot,
heightrounded,
]{geometry} % 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\fancypagestyle{myportland}{
\fancyhead{}% clear all header 
\fancyfoot{}% clear all footer
\fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields  
\fancyhead[L,C,R]{}
\fancyfoot[L,C,R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Página \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newgeometry{
    top=2.54cm,
    bottom=2.54cm,
    left=2.54cm,
    right=2.54cm,
    headheight=17pt, % as per the warning by fancyhdr
    includehead,includefoot,
    heightrounded % to avoid spurious underfull messages
 }
 }
\setlength{\footskip}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myportland}
Something.\footnote{Here is a footnote.} Something else.\footnote{Lorem ipsum   dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi risus lacus, suscipit vehicula ullamcorper a, tempus consectetur.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.